# Is it possible to configure a Java web app to run with Apache Wink Server and JAX-RS 2.0?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs, apache-wink

I switched my application from using a Jersey Server to using an Apache Wink Server. Now, when I make CRUD operations to my API, I get the following error:

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()

I am sure this is happening because my application requires the use of JAX-RS 2.0, but Apache Wink is only JAX-RS 1.1 compliant.

I know that Apache CFX is JAX-RS 2.0 compliant, but I need to use Apache Wink to make the server responses align with a Liberty server (which uses Apache Wink).

So, is it possible to get Apache Wink + JAX-RS 2.0 working together on the same Java web app? And if so, please help me!

Comment: what version of Liberty? 8.5.5.6 [appears](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html?lang=en) to have `<feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>`

Comment: Yeah exactly; my Liberty server uses JAXRS 2.0, but I have an embedded Jetty server to run the same application during build tests. However, this embedded Jetty server currently runs with Jersey under the hood, and therefore the HTTP response errors are sometimes different when using the Liberty server. This is why I want a way to use Apache Wink rather than Jersey under the hood of the Jetty server, b/c Liberty uses Wink under the hood. However, Wink is not JAXRS-2.0 compliant, so I wonder if there is a trick to force is to become so.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't believe the Liberty JAX-RS 2.0 feature uses Wink.  According to the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_jaxrs_secure.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5&lang=en), the JAX-RS 2.0 feature is actually a derivative of [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) 3.0.2. Would you be in able in your Jetty environment or dev build to embed CXF3?